# TortoiseSVN Diff color codes

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, diff, tortoisemerge

Could anyone explain the color codes when doing a diff in SVN, i.e. some lines are marked as red, yellow, blue, etc.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Check the TortoiseSVN Manual: [TortoiseMerge | Colour Settings Page](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseMerge_en/tmerge-dug-settings.html#tmerge-dug-settings-color).

This is the default color scheme (see it in **TortoiseMerge | File | Settings | Colors**):

[image: tortoisemerge default color scheme]

It also makes sense to know the [line status icons](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseMerge_en/tmerge-dug-icons.html) meaning.

Comment: for high contrast color scheme in windows, one can change the colors to red for removal and green for addition (and gray for others)

Comment: @bahrep this is a fantastic answer. +1 for line status icons link as well!

Comment: How do you even get to that context window?

Comment: @RayCheng Start **TortoiseMerge** and go to **File | Settings | Colors**.